# I got an error in my code and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mysql import connector

first_url = "https://www.freelancer.com/jobs/?keyword=python"

response = requests.get(first_url)

page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
items = page.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-item-inner"})
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    title = item.find("a", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-primary-heading-link"}).text.strip()
    timeLeft = item.find("span", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-primary-heading-days"}).text.strip()

    try:
        verified = 'VERIFIED' == item.find("div", attrs={"class":"JobSearchCard-primary-heading-status Tooltip--top"}).text.strip()
    except:
        verified = False

    description = item.find("p", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-primary-description"}).text.strip()
    # do tags section
    price = item.find("div", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-secondary-price"}).text.strip().split()
    price = ' '.join(price)
    bids = int(item.find("div", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-secondary-entry"}).text.strip().split()[0])
    print("title: ", title)
    print("time left: ", timeLeft)
    print("verified: ", verified)
    print("description: ", description)
    print("price: ", price)
    print("bids: ", bids)
    print("\nindex: {} ------------------------------------------------------------------\n".format(index))
```

Hi,
I got this error when i ran my code, I don't know why i got this, PRICE variable shouldn't be NoneType.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jackson\Desktop\GPFW.py", line 22, in <module>
    price = item.find("div", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-secondary-price"}).text.strip().split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If you notice the code, the program should print out TITLE, TIEMLEFT, DESCRIPTION, VERIFIED variables and then print out the error.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error due to this post

[image]

It does not have a price or bids. You can just add a try-except block and set the value you need for bids and price in this post.

```
try:
    price = item.find("div", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-secondary-price"}).text.strip().split()
except AttributeError:
    price=''
price = ' '.join(price)
try:
    bids = int(item.find("div", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-secondary-entry"}).text.strip().split()[0])
except AttributeError:
    bids=''
```

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll through the list of results from the source's web page, there is a row that has does not have a price (nor bid) posted. So at the time of writing, the error is legitimate because the element you are looking for does not exist for that entry.

To resolve your issue, simple add a check whether if the element exists. If so, then extract the text

```
price = item.find("div", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-secondary-price"})
if price:
    price = price.text.strip().split()
else:
    price = "No Avg Price"
```

Answer (score 0):

the nonetype error is caused by the ***"item.find("div", attrs={"class": "JobSearchCard-secondary-price"})"*** not being a usable data type e.g string instead of int or  a custom type e.g a name type, so you may want to have a look at the data you are receiving when you run that line and if possible convert it into a usable data type before trying to format it.